# How do I restrict the type of React Children in TypeScript, using the newly added support in TypeScript 2.3?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to take advantage of the [recently added support for typing of children](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/15160) in the TypeScript compiler and @types/react, but struggling. I'm using TypeScript version 2.3.4.

Say I have code like this:

```
interface TabbedViewProps {children?: Tab[]}
export class TabbedView extends React.Component<TabbedViewProps, undefined> {

  render(): JSX.Element {
    return <div>TabbedView</div>;
  }
}

interface TabProps {name: string}
export class Tab extends React.Component<TabProps, undefined> {
  render(): JSX.Element {
    return <div>Tab</div>
  }
}
```

When I try to use these components like so:

```
return <TabbedView>
  <Tab name="Creatures">
    <div>Creatures!</div>
  </Tab>
  <Tab name="Combat">
    <div>Combat!</div>
  </Tab>
</TabbedView>;
```

I get an error as follows:

```
ERROR in ./src/typescript/PlayerView.tsx
(27,12): error TS2322: Type '{ children: Element[]; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<TabbedView> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> ...'.
  Type '{ children: Element[]; }' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<TabbedViewProps>'.
    Types of property 'children' are incompatible.
      Type 'Element[]' is not assignable to type 'Tab[] | undefined'.
        Type 'Element[]' is not assignable to type 'Tab[]'.
          Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'Tab'.
            Property 'render' is missing in type 'Element'.
```

It seems to be inferring the type of children as just `Element[]` instead of `Tab[]` even though that's the only type of children I'm using.

EDIT: It would also be fine to restrict the interface of the *children props* instead of restricting the type of the children components directly, since all I need to do is pull some specific props out of the children components.

Comment: Take a look at React.PropsWithChildren<Props>

Comment: See similar solutions here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68397897/typing-a-react-component-factory-function/68433032#68433032 and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68278567/react-ts-generic-component-to-pass-generic-props-to-children#answer-68442669

Answer (score 59):

**Edit 2: Turns out that this approach prevent the warning, but according to the comments `TabProps` aren't properly checked.**

You should try to set children of interface TabbedViewProps like so

```
interface TabbedViewProps { children?: React.ReactElement<TabProps>[] }
```

The idea here is not to tell your `TabbedView` has an array of `Tab`, but instead tell your `TabbedView` he has an array of `element` which takes specific props. In your case `TabProps`.

Edit ( thx to Matei ):

```
interface TabbedViewProps {
    children?: React.ReactElement<TabProps>[] | React.ReactElement<TabProps>
}
```

Comment: I follow a similar approach: `children?: Array<React.ReactChild> | React.ReactChild`. This way the component can accept even a single child and not necessarily an array of children.

Comment: I have a similar problem. In my case, I defined type of children(which is TabProps) just like you did, but when I place an element as TabbedView's child which does not shaped like TabProps, typescript does not report any error or warning. Can you give some advice or clue?

Comment: Same issue as @Noah. It seems that you can restrict children only to an extent, but restricting to child elements *with certain props* just doesn't work. It'll make sure its an element, but props don't matter. Bummer!

Comment: Does Typescript plan to properly type props of a child element?

Comment: I’m facing the same problem. TypeScript does not check the type of children even though I define the `children` type like above.

Comment: It looks like wrapping the props with ReactElement loosens the type so that any element is actually allowed.  Here is what I get when hovering over my customer element: `type ChartElement<T> = ReactElement<ChartProps<T>, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)>`  Note the `|(props: any) =>`.

Comment: @zmou-d running into this same problem. Did you already come to a fix for this issue?

Comment: @MapMyMind I have got the same issue, did you find a solution?

Comment: After reading all the comments and answers in detail, I want to state explicitly (because no one has yet): **this is not possible** as of writing. That is, you can't raise an error if the wrong type of children are passed, which is what the question asks.

Answer (score 26):

As pointer out already, declaring `TabbedView.children` as:

```
children: React.ReactElement<TabProps> | React.ReactElement<TabProps>[];
```

Will get rid of the error, but it won't be type-checking the children properly. That is, you will still be able to pass children other than `TabProps` to `TabbedView` without getting any error, so this would also be valid:

```
return (
  <TabbedView>
    <Tab name="Creatures">
      <div>Creatures!</div>
    </Tab>

    <Tab name="Combat">
        <div>Combat!</div>
    </Tab>

    <NotTabButValidToo />
  </TabbedView>
);
```

What you could do instead is declare a prop, let's say `tabs: TabProps[]`, to pass down the props you need to create those `Tab`s, rather than their JSX, and render them inside `TabbedView`:

```
interface TabbedViewProps {
  children?: never;
  tabs?: TabProps[];
}

...

const TabbedView: React.FC<TabbedViewProps> = ({ tabs }) => {
  return (
    ...

    { tabs.map(tab => <Tab key={ ... } { ...tab } />) }

    ...
  );
};
```

Comment: Been researching this for a while and I think this is the best method given the children limitations

Comment: Opting for a worse API just because type checker limitations doesn't seem like a smart decision to me.

Comment: IMO It's not a worse api, but a better one. Just because it's maybe not so easy to type doesn't mean it is objectively "worse". This api more clearly expresses what is wanted. We want a list of tabs (which is what the typings clearly say). Now their is no `React.Children` nonsense as well. This approach really should be more idiomatic

Comment: there is no way that passing one big data object to a React component is more idiomatic than using JSX's built-in children feature. if that were the case, all of our data would be stored in one massive object rather than spread out throughout the React tree

Answer (score 5):

I tried to assert the type.
You can throw or just ignore.

```
interface TabbedViewProps {
  children?: React.ReactElement<ITabProps> | React.ReactElement<ITabProps>[]
}
```

And in the component itself map the children and assert or ignore

```
{React.Children.map(props.children, (tab) => {
  if(tab?.type != Tab) return;
  console.log(tab?.type == Tab);
  return tab;
})}
```

Comment: What is "Tab" in `ab?.type != Tab`

Answer (score 0):

These answers show the general idea, but they don't allow you to pass children like:

```
<MyParentComponent>
  {condition && <Child1/>}
  {list.map((it) => <Child2 x={it}/>}
</MyParentComponent>
```

I took some inspiration from the definition of `children` in `type PropsWithChildren<P>` from the React (v16.14.21) codebase:

```
type PropsWithChildren<P> = P & { children?: ReactNode | undefined };

type ReactText = string | number;
type ReactChild = ReactElement | ReactText;

interface ReactNodeArray extends Array<ReactNode> {}
type ReactFragment = {} | ReactNodeArray;
type ReactNode = ReactChild | ReactFragment | ReactPortal | boolean | null | undefined;
```

and came up with a simplified definition that fits my use case:

```
type TypedReactNode<T> = ReactElement<T> | Array<TypedReactNode<T>> | null | undefined;
type PropsWithTypedChildren<P, C> = P & { children?: TypedReactNode<C> | undefined };
```

Finally, I can define my component like so:

```
type MyParentComponentProps = {
  whatever: string;
};

const MyParentComponent = (props: PropsWithTypedChildren<MyParentComponentProps, AllowedChildType>) => {
  // body
}
```

Comment: Interesting, can't seem to get an error when I put something else in my parent though.

Comment: One other thing: `MyParentComponentProps['children']` will not work either.

Answer (score -3):

Type you are returning in Tab render method is JSX.Element. This is what causes your problem. TabbedView is expecting array of childrens with type Tab. I am not sure if you can specify a certain component as a children type. It can be string or JSX.Element. Can you show the definition file for Tab?

Look at https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts to see how JSX.Element interface looks.

Comment: I showed the entire definition of TabbedView and Tab in the first code block. The whole point of the new support for children types *seems* to be to allow restricting the components (if you see the issue that it's supposed to resolve linked at the top of the PR), so I think I must be missing something.

Comment: You have showed a definition of the component. Not interface.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking for, I'm sorry :( This is the entirety of my Tab-related code in my tsx project. I would be happy to try to provide what you're asking for but I think I'm going to need a little bit of help.

Comment: edited: still not working. I tried React.ReactElement<TabProps>, which seemed to work, but didn't properly reject non-Tab components in the children.

Comment: You are using instance of react component as a type (interface). https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html

Comment: I don't understand. Can you point out exactly where I'm using an instance of a React component as a type?