# TypeScript React Function Component name as type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In `React.js`, I've got a `Function Component`, and when I use the function name as `type`, get an error.

code sample:

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

interface NameViewProps {
  name: string;
}
function NameView({ name }: NameViewProps) {
  return <div>{name}</div>;
}

interface Props {
  // ts error: Cannot find name 'NameView'.ts(2304)
  children: NameView[];
}

class Demo extends React.Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>in demo component with children div array</h2>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

How can I use a function component’s name as a `type`?

You can try the [codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-river-ds6yd)

Comment: What is that type supposed to mean? It makes no sense to use a function as a type.

Comment: How do you want to use ```Demo```? Why do you want to limit its children to a specific type?

Comment: @AsukaSong I think it’s better to provide a specific type for `children` if we can. So we can prevent users of our component from passing the wrong children.

Comment: @MuratKaragöz I want to limit the `Demo` component only accepting children of `NameView` component, not others like `div` or `span`.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44475309/how-do-i-restrict-the-type-of-react-children-in-typescript-using-the-newly-adde

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restrict the type of React Children in TypeScript, using the newly added support in TypeScript 2.3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44475309/how-do-i-restrict-the-type-of-react-children-in-typescript-using-the-newly-adde)

Answer (score 1):

```
interface Props {
  children: (typeof NameView)[];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use typeof (function name) i.e typeof NameView