# React/TypeScript: Specifically type props.children to component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Let's say we have a component `Foo` that renders `props.children` and another component `Bar`. Both modules export a props interface.

Is there a way to enforce that `Foo`'s children can be **only** of type `Bar`?

Ideally we could accomplish this with TypeScript at build-time.

Example:

```
import { createElement, FC, ReactNode } from 'react';
import { Bar, BarProps } from '../Bar';

export interface FooProps {
  children?: ReactNode; // this works
  // children?: ReactNode<BarProps>; // nope
  // children?: Bar; // nope
}

export const Foo: FC<FooProps> = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Note: we are not using PropTypes

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need a strong requirement on props.children?

Comment: Our internal component library needs to abide by a fairly strict UX specification/design guide. A contrived example would be that Table shouldn't be allowed to be a child of a Dropdown component.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49408900/9124424))

```
export interface FooProps {
  children?: React.ReactElement<BarProps> | React.ReactElement<BarProps>[]
}
```

Comment: I think you meant `React.ReactElement<BarProps>[]`?

Comment: If the children of `Foo` need to be completely strict to accepting a component with the type signature of `Bar`  this will not work. Try rendering a simple `h1` element as children to `Foo` (`<Foo><h1>Hello</h1></Foo>`) and you will see that the compiler doesn't even complain.

Comment: I tried this out, and I'm still able to pass non-Bar components in as children of Foo with no compiler warnings/errors

Comment: If you read further in the reference above you'll see "Will get rid of the error, but it won't be type-checking the children properly", I think this is the closest you will get for restricting in the FooProps interface. Maybe throw an error or filter wrong types at the beginning of your component will do the trick?