# Strictly type "slot" props to particular functional components

Tags: reactjs, typescript

As a contrived example, define a few components:

*Lettuce.tsx*:

```
import { createElement, FC } from 'react';
export interface LettuceProps {}
export const Lettuce: FC<LettuceProps> = () => <h4 style={{ color: 'green' }}>Lettuce</h4>;
```

*Tomato.tsx*:

```
import { createElement, FC } from 'react';
export interface TomatoProps {}
export const Tomato: FC<TomatoProps> = () => <h4 style={{ color: 'red' }}>Tomato</h4>;
```

*Tiger.tsx*:

```
import { createElement, FC } from 'react';
export interface TigerProps {}
export const Tomato: FC<TigerProps> = () => <h4 style={{ color: 'orange' }}>Tiger</h4>;
```

*Salad.tsx*:

```
import { createElement, FC, ReactNode } from 'react';
export interface SaladProps {
  ingredients?: ReactNode[];
}
export const Salad: FC<SaladProps> = (props) => (
  <div>
    <h2>Salad</h2>
    {props.ingredients}
  </div>
);
```

Is there a way to have this usage be flagged by the compiler? (a salad cannot contain a tiger):

```
const SaladInvalid = () => (
  <Salad ingredients={[<Lettuce />, <Tomato />, <Tomato />, <Tiger />]} />
);
```

More generally, **is there a way to strictly type "slot" props with TypeScript**?

Note: this question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62678575/2295034) regarding `props.children`

Comment: I don't think you can. The constructor of rendered JSX does not seem to be part its type.