# Why the compiler does allow to compile?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have created the following component:

```
export default function IdeaInfos({children}: { children: ReactElement<IdeaInfoProp, typeof IdeaInfo> }) {
    const classes = useStyles()

    return (
        <Grid container
              justify="center"
              alignItems="center"
              className={classes.wrapper}>
            {children}
        </Grid>
    )
}
```

The component should restrict the type of the passed children, in this case is(this is how I expect to be), the children can only be the component of `IdeaInfo` and properties `IdeaInfoProp`.

However, when I use the component `IdeaInfos`

```
<IdeaInfos>
   <Typography>
       Hello
   </Typography>
</IdeaInfos>
```

it is also possible to pass `Typography` as a child of `IdeaInfos`.
Why does the compiler not complain? I have done the type restriction.

**Update**

Sorry I forgot the share `IdeaInfoProp` and `IdeaInfo`:

```
export interface IdeaInfoProp {
    icon: string,
    text: string,
    textBgColor: string,
    alt: string
    reverse?: boolean,
}

export default function IdeaInfo({icon, text, textBgColor, alt, reverse = false}: IdeaInfoProp) {

    const classes = useStyles()

    return (
        <Grid item container xs={12} direction={reverse ? "row-reverse" : "row"}>
            <Grid item xs={12} md={6} style={{background: `${textBgColor}`}}>
                <Typography className={classes.text} variant="h4">
                    {text}
                </Typography>
            </Grid>
            <Grid
                item
                xs={12}
                md={6}
                container
                justify="center"
                alignItems="center"
            >
                <img src={icon} alt={alt} className={classes.mediaIcon}/>
            </Grid>

        </Grid>
    )

}
```

I have took `Typography` just for demonstration but it comes from https://material-ui.com/components/typography/#typography

Comment: What is `IdeaInfoProp` & `IdeaInfo`? What is the type of `Typography`?

Comment: This is the best answer available I think → https://stackoverflow.com/a/59418019/6141587

Comment: Could you please guide me, how to solve it?

Comment: @zero_coding Use a custom prop instead of `children`.

Comment: @Sulthan How to do it? I am pretty new in React world.