# React TS Generic component to pass generic props to children

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to create a React component that is somewhat like an Accordion. It will have children and allow opening/closing each. Each child is also a React component that needs unique props from the parent that other children may not use. I assumed I need to use Generics to facilitate these varying props.

I have this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/generic-ts-react-component-pt96w?file=/src/App.tsx) project with my attempt.

Comment: I'm not understanding what exactly your asking, or what is being presented in that codesandbox.  Can you please explain.  If you are trying to restrict what type of children a component may have, or what type of props those child components may have, take a gander at [How do I restrict the type of React Children in TypeScript, using the newly added support in TypeScript 2.3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44475309/how-do-i-restrict-the-type-of-react-children-in-typescript-using-the-newly-adde)

Comment: I want a component that takes a set of defined props (X) and some additional arbitrary ones (Y). Part of X will be Components, those components should be passed a set of defined props (Z) AND Y from before.

Comment: I believe this would be way better than using a lot of props configuration: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/compound-components-with-react-hooks

Comment: Thanks, @Noriller , currently trialing Compound components with Context and Render props and it seems much nicer and more readable.

Answer (score 3):

To pass components as a prop, use `ComponentType` instead of `FC`

```
type SubSectionToggleProps<T> = {
  subSections: ComponentType<SubSectionBaseProps>[];
} & T;
```

You might have to type-assert the passed-in components

```
<SubSectionToggle<{ title: string; count: number }>
  title="Hello"
  count={2}
  subSections={[Component1, Component2] as ComponentType<SubSectionBaseProps>[]}
/>
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/generic-ts-react-component-forked-s6sp1?file=/src/App.tsx)

Answer (score 1):

One way you can render the child `isOpen` props when they are managed by the container is like this:

```js
import React from 'react';
import "./styles.css";

// the container is your list
interface ContainerProps {
}
interface ContainerState {
  // keep an array of isOpen variables in the state of the container
  open: boolean[];
}
class Container extends React.Component<React.PropsWithChildren<ContainerProps>, ContainerState> {
  public constructor(props: React.PropsWithChildren<ContainerProps>) {
    super(props);
    // initialize the isOpens
    this.state = {
      open: React.Children.toArray(this.props.children).map((_) => {return false;}),
    };
  }

  public readonly render = () => {
    // clone the children and specify their isOpen props here
    return (
     <>
       {React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child, i) => {
         if(React.isValidElement(child)) {
           return(React.cloneElement(child, {isOpen: this.state.open[i]}));
         }
         return child;
       })}
     </>
    );
  };
}

// props for all list items to extend. The isOpen is allowed to be undefined for when the component is not in a list
interface ComponentProps {
  isOpen?: boolean;
}

// component A uses a number
interface ComponentAProps extends ComponentProps {
  count: number;
}
class ComponentA extends React.Component<ComponentAProps> {
  public readonly render = () => {
    return (
      <p>
        {`count: ${this.props.count}, open: ${this.props.isOpen}`}
      </p>
    );
  };
}

// component B uses a string
interface ComponentBProps extends ComponentProps {
  title: string;
}
class ComponentB extends React.Component<ComponentBProps> {
  public readonly render = () => {
    return (
      <p>
        {`title: ${this.props.title}, open: ${this.props.isOpen}`}
      </p>
    );
  };
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Container>
      <ComponentA count={2}/>
      <ComponentB title='hello'/>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

You make the `isOpen` prop optional. That way the list component can feed in the isOpen to the children, while the specification of the children can ignore the `isOpen` prop.

Comment: This is a nicer way of doing it but making `isOpen` optional would require null checks on it which isn't great especially that it's always present.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify generic prop types, and let TypeScript handle the inference accordingly. TypeScript is pretty gosh darn good at inferring generic type arguments.

```
type AccordionProps<T> = {
  value: T
  onChange: (newValue: T) => unknown
}

function Accordion<T>(props: AccordionProps<T>) {
  ...
}

function Parent() {
  // newValue correctly typed as (newValue: string) => unknown
  return <Accordion value="asdf" onChange={(newValue) => doSomething(newValue)} />
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I used [Currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying).

It is easier to infer all generics.

**Curry**

This function takes two components and thanks to [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) infers each component. More about inference you can find [in my article](https://dev.to/captainyossarian/typescript-type-inference-on-function-arguments-2n93)

**Component validation**

`Curry` function also validates each component to make sure each accepts `BaseProps`.

```js
import React, { FC } from "react";

type BaseProps = {
  isOpen: boolean;
};

const WithTitle: FC<BaseProps & { title: string }> = ({ isOpen, title }) => (
  <p>
    Component 1: isOpen: {isOpen.toString()}. Title: {title}
  </p>
);
const WithCount: FC<BaseProps & { count: number }> = ({ isOpen, count }) => (
  <p>
    Component 2: isOpen: {isOpen.toString()}. Count: {count}
  </p>
);

type GetRequired<T> =
  // make sure we have a deal with array
  T extends Array<infer F>
    ? // make sure that element in the array extends FC
      F extends FC<infer Props>
      ? // if Props extends BaseProps
        Props extends BaseProps
        ? // Omit isOpen property, since it is not needed
          Omit<Props, "isOpen">
        : never
      : never
    : never;

type ExtractProps<F extends FC<any>> = F extends FC<infer Props>
  ? Props
  : never;

type IsValid<Components extends Array<FC<BaseProps>>> = 
    ExtractProps<[...Components][number]> extends BaseProps ? Components : never

// credits goes to https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends (
  k: infer I
) => void
  ? I
  : never;

const Curry =
  <Comps extends FC<any>[], Valid extends IsValid<Comps>>(
    /**
     * If each Component expects BaseProps,
     * sections argument will evaluate to [...Comps] & [...Comps],
     * otherwise to [...Comps] & never === never
     */
    sections: [...Comps] & Valid
  ) =>
  /**
   * GetRequired<[...Comps]> returns a union
   * when we need an intersection of all extra properties from 
   * all passed components
   *
   */
  (props: UnionToIntersection<GetRequired<[...Comps]>>) =>
    (
      <>
        {sections.map((Comp: FC<BaseProps>) => (
          <Comp isOpen={true} {...props} /> // isOpen is required
        ))}
      </>
    );

const Container = Curry([WithCount, WithTitle]);

const result = <Container title={"hello"} count={42} />; // ok

const result_ = <Container title={"hello"} count={"42"} />; // expected error

const Container_ = Curry([WithCount, () => null]); // expected error
```

As you might have noticed, dealing with `FC<Props>` is tricky. I have used `UnionToIntersection`. This is because `Props` is in contravariant position to `FC`.

```js
declare var foo: FC<BaseProps & { count: number }>;
declare var baz: FC<BaseProps>;

foo = baz // ok
baz = foo // error

// REMOVE FC wrapper

declare var foo_: BaseProps & { count: number };
declare var baz_: BaseProps;

foo_ = baz_ // error
baz_ = foo_ // ok
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of passing components in as a prop, pass them in as child components:

```
<SubSectionToggle>
   <Component1 title={"Hello"} isOpen={true} />
   <Component2 count={2} isOpen={true} />
</SubSectionToggle>
```

You can then render the children like this:

```
const SubSectionToggle = ({children}): ReactElement => {
  return (
    <>
      {children}
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: The value of `isOpen` is managed by `SubSectionToggle`, how can I pass it into the child components?

Comment: I feel like this doesn't really answer the question