# Typing a React Component Factory Function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, factory, type-constraints, tsx

Given the type

```js
type EnumerableComponentFactory = <C, I>(config: {
  Container: React.ComponentType<C>;
  Item: React.ComponentType<I>;
}) => React.FC<{ items: I[] }>;
```

with the following implementation

```js
const Enumerable: EnumerableComponentFactory =
  ({ Container, Item }) =>
  ({ items }) =>
    (
      <Container>
        {items.map((props, index) => (
          <Item key={index} {...props} />
        ))}
      </Container>
    );
```

and intended use

```js
const UnorderedList = Enumerable({
  Container: ({ children }) => <ul>{children}</ul>,
  Item: ({ title }: { title: string }) => <li>{title}</li>,
});

<UnorderedList items=[{title: "Something"}] />
```

I'm observing the following TypeScript error

```
Type '{ children: Element[]; }' is not assignable to type 'C'.
  'C' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to '{ children: Element[]; }'.ts(2322)
```

which leads me to my question: What type constraints do I need to set up to resolve this error?

I've tried to change the type as follows:

```js
type EnumerableComponentFactory = <C extends { children?: Element[] }, I>(config: {
  Container: ComponentType<C>;
  Item: ComponentType<I>;
}) => (props: { items: I[] }) => ReturnType<FC<I>>;
```

but this produces an even more cryptic error message, which I'm going to omit for the sake of brevity.

---

P.S. The function itself actually does exactly what's expected. It's just the compiler that trips up.

Answer (score 1):

Is it necessary to keep `C` generic parameter?

```js
import React, { FC, ComponentType, PropsWithChildren } from "react";

type EnumerableComponentFactory = <I>(config: {
  // or Container: FC<{ children: JSX.Element[] }>;
  Container: FC<PropsWithChildren<object>>;
  Item: ComponentType<I>;
}) => FC<{ items: I[] }>;

const Enumerable: EnumerableComponentFactory =
  ({ Container, Item }) =>
  ({ items }) =>
    (
      <Container>
        {items.map((props, index) => (
          <Item key={index} {...props} />
        ))}
      </Container>
    );

const UnorderedList = Enumerable({
  Container: ({ children }) => <ul>{children}</ul>,
  Item: ({ title }: { title: string }) => <li>{title}</li>,
});

const result = <UnorderedList items={[{ title: "Something" }]} />;
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to alter your code to make it work, while also accepting other props to be passed to the container:

```js
type EnumerableComponentFactory = <C, I>(config: {
    Container: React.ComponentType<C & { children: React.ReactNode[] }>;
    Item: React.ComponentType<I>;
}) => React.ComponentType<C & { items: I[] }>;

const Enumerable: EnumerableComponentFactory = ({ Container, Item }) => (
    props
) => (
    <Container {...props}>
        {props.items.map((props, index) => (
            <Item key={index} {...props} />
        ))}
    </Container>
);
```

Which allows for e.g. this:

```js
const ContainerWithBorder: React.ComponentType<{ color: string }> = (props) => (
    <div style={{ border: `2px solid ${props.color}` }}>
        <ul>{props.children}</ul>
    </div>
);

const ComplexList = Enumerable({
    Container: ContainerWithBorder,
    Item: ({ title }: { title: string }) => <li>{title}</li>
});

<ComplexList items={[{ title: "Something" }]} color="red" />
```

The `ComplexList` component comes with typing/intellisense for the `color` property.

*A playground with the original and `ComplexList` example can be found [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-playground-forked-hyqju?file=/src/index.tsx).*