# Typescript: Pass component given props to the component's children prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

The thing I'd like to achieve is to create generic-typed component which would accept different props (based on its usage in project), then finally output its' children prop with all the given props (flow-through) + possibly some new consts (which would be calculated based on the props), like so:

```
const bonus1 = { offerId: 1, offerDate: 1911 }
const bonus2 = { offerId: 2, timeLeft: 100 }
const bonus3 = { offerId: 3, offerDate: 1991, isActive: true }

<Bonus {...bonus1}>
{({ offerId, offerDate, onClick }) => {})
</Bonus>

<Bonus {...bonus2}>
{({ offerId, timeLeft, onClick }) => {})
</Bonus>

<Bonus {...bonus3}>
{({ offerId, offerDate, isActive, onClick }) => {})
</Bonus>
```

I've prepared some common type with fields I know every `bonus` would have, like: `offerId`:

```
type BonusCommon = { offerId: number }
```

Now the component types:

```
type BonusProps<T> = {
  children: (renderProps: RenderProps<T>) => ReactNode
} & T

type RenderProps<T> = {
  onClick: () => void
} & T // here is what I thought would work, ie. pass to `children` all the input props
```

And the component itself:

```
const Bonus = <T extends BonusCommon>({
  children,
  offerId,
  ...rest, // the rest of the input props
}: BonusProps<T>) => {
  const onClick = () => {} // do something with available props

  return (
    <>
      children({ // TS ERROR!
        onClick,
        offerId,
        ...rest
      })
    </>
  )
}
```

I am out of ideas that would actually make it work, cos currently there's an error saying: `'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'BonusCommon'`

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBCEB2BXAzgYQgFsis4BeOAbwCg44IAzR4KASQBMAuOHIgI1Y0AvjRpIUcAErBMHVvgAWASwA2HKLIA8AFQB8FanQaZ8q5QGMA1jwAUASgoGAbhGUcRcAGRwdY0JCwCMioGDi4AApQEGC4unCgMLIcuOhYeIQkWAaUtPQWKuqamHZg0bE8MnIKhRra+o7kBgCGmIiePn40AdDwFli48GF4hvGJyanDBMSkmHq2eXAFanWYADTGTCzsHBv0AHSHmoMiPFNRMXENTkb5A-BYZpZWhg43VKLGmjDYUJhLtWKC2M9Ee5mse3oDGYrE4kIOR2AJ3ownsIiAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export type BonusCommon = {
  offerId: number
}

type RenderChildren<T> = {
  onClick: () => void
} & T

export type BonusProps<T extends BonusCommon> = {
  children: (props: RenderChildren<T>) => any
} & T

export const Bonus = <T extends BonusCommon>({
  children,
  ...rest
}: BonusProps<T>) => {
  const onClick = () => {}

  return children({
    onClick,
    ...(rest as unknown as T),
  })
}
```

- `offerId` need to be part of `rest` that way you can say it's a type `T`
- now `{ onClick: () => void; } & Omit<BonusProps<T>, "children">` type doesn't match with `RenderChildren<T>` so, first cast an `unknown` and then as `T`

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to infer all types you want without `type assertion`.

In order to do it you just need to `curry` your component.

```js
import React from 'react'

export type BonusCommon = {
  offerId: number
}

type ClickHandler = {
  onClick: () => void
}

export type BonusProps<T> = T & ClickHandler

type RenderChildren<T> = {
  children: (props: T) => JSX.Element
}

export const withRest = <
  Keys extends PropertyKey,
  Value,
  Rest extends Record<Keys, Value>,
  >(initialProps: Rest) => <
    OfferId extends BonusCommon,
    Children extends RenderChildren<BonusCommon & ClickHandler & Rest>
  >({
    children,
    offerId,
  }: OfferId & Children) => {
    const onClick = () => { }
    return children({ ...initialProps, offerId, onClick })
  }
const Bonus = withRest({ hello: 1 })

const jsx = <Bonus offerId={42}>{
  (elem) => {
    elem.offerId // ok
    elem.hello // ok

    elem.onClick // ok
    return <div></div>
  }

}</Bonus>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChSkAPSWOGATzCTgCEIA7AVwGcBhXEBzgBeOAG9ScOBEyYkUAJIATAFxwuIAEbzSAX3IMmcXgBtgaANYAJFOyUn5I8ZOntT5i2oAUAShEA%20OAA3CGAlPXIqGnhDZjYubgAFHDBuAB4AFUDRDLgAMmMzSxs7BygDRmZkO3leAAtgEyUidkzs5yk0BqaW7zAU7jUMv2FAgCkAZQANADoAUQcQJHYYCIpqaHg0Dm54AHdgGDrkXac0lwBpJHpuOCoYZaVb5IgmWHor%20gAaFwA1FBMnCQPykJ3g90et2Q2ygSjSn24Xzg-0BSH8ILg-i8wHYh2AAJeqTUYJGgXOUikAHlZPJlHdKA87Ld4jx%20CBBOwMVJ6o1mst6YynohHrVunzWiy%20AIhAV3MVbPZHAUwf4XFiJBS4F1eS0udIaYolBjdGpqXJDfljGKWqSOhTtuxThw5RYnL4AuI4PpNUQYJwoOwtdbll4xHAZhGcXiCQMkTJzco424iq7dD4XPoHadJU4DkcwaG4HUkCYTBA1ABGL3p0hZ%20AAK24lDOOfjtKUwjEABYAEy6fwauBeEtIEC2wdSEcgGZti0Aejn0gsLknixmxdLEDgC6X5E1U5nyY828XEGXPqQfoDcDSSmAQX8aTnd4fGfIuifkv8QA)

`withRest` is a function which expects `rest` props and returns valid React component. Returned component in turn knows about `Rest` props and able to handle them.

As you might have noticed, `children` callback argument is aware about all props.

Related answers:[First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68397897/typing-a-react-component-factory-function/68433032#68433032), [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68278567/react-ts-generic-component-to-pass-generic-props-to-children/#68442669) and my [article](https://catchts.com/currying-components)

If you want to learn more about argument inference you can read [this](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments)