# Can I type React Children using Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, children, react-typescript

I'm using styled-components to build a message card component.  I'm trying to make it have as little logic and take as few props as possible, so I'm using CSS to style any `<p>` or `<svg>` elements that are passed in as children like so:

[image: Screenshot of MessageCard being used next to desired outcome.]

I'm also using typescript and I'd like to ensure that the only element types passed in as children are a minimum of 1 paragraph element and 1 SVG element?

Something like this for example:

```
type = MessageCardProps = {
  children: [ JSXSVGElement?, JSXParagraphElement, JSXParagraphElement]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is currently not possible to implement it the way you want. Unfortunately `ReactElement` loosens type checking as described here: [How do I restrict the type of React Children in TypeScript, using the newly added support in TypeScript 2.3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44475309/how-do-i-restrict-the-type-of-react-children-in-typescript-using-the-newly-adde)

After all [Reacts Composition](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html) to use the props to pass this to your component with the [appropriate types](https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/basic/getting-started/basic_type_example/#useful-react-prop-type-examples):

```
import { ComponentPropsWithoutRef, PropsWithChildren } from "react";

type MessageCardProps = PropsWithChildren<{
  icon: ComponentPropsWithoutRef<"svg">;
  title: string;
}>;

function MessageCard({ icon, title, children }: MessageCardProps) {
  return <div>{icon}{title}{children}</div>;
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <MessageCard icon={<svg></svg>} title="title">
      message
    </MessageCard>
  );
}
```